# Navigation On The web react-navigation

Tags: react-native, modal-dialog, react-navigation, react-native-web

So i was wondering is there a comprehensive example or library out there that one could use for navigation on web as well as native side.

Maybe a working example one could try out with modal, drawers, and all that fancy stuff.

What is it like using react-navigation 3.0 for web? Is it fully compatible? Is there an example online one could work with and draw inspiration from?
The example on react-navigation documentation is pretty contrived and not really clear, is there someone who has worked on such project.

Thanks.

Here are a few sources i have come across.

https://blog.bitsrc.io/how-to-react-native-web-app-a-happy-struggle-aea7906f4903

How about using an HOC as provided in the above case?

Seems like a neat solution.

https://pickering.org/using-react-native-react-native-web-and-react-navigation-in-a-single-project-cfd4bcca16d0

https://reactnavigation.org/blog/#ecosystem-and-web-support

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/web-support.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no perfect example of rn-web plus r-navigation.

Have a look at: https://github.com/react-native-elements

PS:Honestly this is (for me) a dependency hell "r, rn, rn-web, rn-dom, babel, expo, expo-cli". Frameworks & repos owners around the RN topic do not seems too concerned about the react-native-web topic anyway.